# Prove that there are no tournament with exactly two champions.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let's define a **tournament** as a contest among $n$ players where each player plays a game agains each other player and there are no draws. Now let me define a **tournament champion**.

**A tournament champion** is a player $c$ where, for each other player $p$ in the tournament, either

- $c$ won his/her game against $p$, or
- there’s a player $q$ where $c$ won his/her game against $q$ and $q$ won his/her game against $p$.

I need to prove the following:

> Prove that there are no tournaments with exactly two champions.

Before this theorem I proved this (let's call it **Theorem 1**):

> Let T be an arbitrary tournament. Prove that if p is a player in T who lost at least one game, then at least one of the players who won against p is a tournament champion.

My attempt to prove is the following:

Let $T$ be an arbitrary tournament. We will prove that $T$ has less than or more than 2 champions. To do so, we proceed by contradiction; assume that there are exactly two champions in $T$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the only champions in $T$. Then, using a corollary of [this my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734506/tournament-championship-proof) (*every tournament with at least one player has at least one tournament champion*) we know that our champions either both won the greatest number of games or only one of them won the greatest number of games. Therefore we proceed by cases:

*Case 1*: **they won equal number of games**. Notice, that one of the champions must win another, therefore without loss of generality assume that $a$ won $b$. Since they won equal number of games, we know that there must exist a player who won $a$, but loss $b$. Therefore using **Theorem 1** we see that there must be another champion, so there are more than 2 champions, therefore we have reached contradiction.

*Case 2*: **one of the champions won more games than another**. Without loss of generality assume that $a$ won more games than $b$.

I think I understand how I can proceed in my second case to show a contradiction, but it seems that I need even more branching what I don't like, therefore I believe there is more sophisticated proof of this theorem.

Could someone please take a look at my proof and criticize my style of writing. Also I would be very grateful if you could provide any hints to a better solution if there are any.

**UPDATE:**
Hmm, I looked a bit carefully at the problem and believe that it's easier than I thought. Assume we have only two champions in $T$. They are $a$ and $b$. We know that either $a$ won $b$ or $b$ won $a$. Without loss of generality assume that $a$ won $b$. Since $b$ is a champion, there must exist a player who won $a$, but lost $b$. Using **Theorem 1** we see that there is at least one more champion in $T$. This contradicts our assumption that we have exactly two champions.

Is this correct proof or am I missing something?